# split statement in truthable

Tags: prolog

So I made a Prolog program that takes any number of parameters such as A B C and a statement and prints its truth table.
What if I want to split each statement alone and show its truth table as well?
example and(or(A,B),and(A,B)).
so it should show

```
A  B  or(A,B) and(A,B)  full equation      
T   T     T     T           T             
T  F      T     F           T
```

I noticed the method split_string but I don't know how to use it in my case
here is my code:

```
table(VarList,Expr) :- bindList(VarList), do(VarList,Expr), fail.

bind(true).
bind(false).

bindList([]).

bindList([V|Vs]) :- bind(V),bindList(Vs).

do(VarList,Expr) :- writeVarList(VarList), writeExpr(Expr), nl.

writeVarList([]).
writeVarList([V|Vs]) :- write(V), write('  '), writeVarList(Vs).

writeExpr(Expr) :- Expr, !, write(true).
writeExpr(_) :- write(false).
```

Comment: Can you give an example query? Are you really inputting the expression as a string or as a Prolog expression? `split_string` is probably inappropriate for what you want to achive.

Comment: i dont really know how to do it @lurker

Comment: You wrote some code. How did you intend to call it (show an example)? That's all I'm asking.

Comment: dude i wrote a code for the whole equation,when it comes to splitting idk how should i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to evaluate subexpressions separately, you need to write code to compute those subexpressions. There is an easy way to do it with backtracking, although here a list seems more appropriate. Here is a DCG that computes all `and` and `or` subexpressions, but leaves out the variable leaves:

```
subexprs(V) -->
    { var(V), ! },
    [].
subexprs(and(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [and(L, R)].
subexprs(or(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [or(L, R)].
```

With this list in hand, you can then bind the variables and evaluate the subexpressions one by one using `maplist/2`, if your Prolog has it:

```
?- phrase(subexprs(and(or(A, B), and(A, B))), Subexprs), bindlist([A,B]), maplist(write_expr, Subexprs), nl.
 true true true
A = B, B = true,
Subexprs = [or(true, true), and(true, true), and(or(true, true), and(true, true))] ;
 true false false
A = true,
B = false,
Subexprs = [or(true, false), and(true, false), and(or(true, false), and(true, false))] ;
 true false false
A = false,
B = true,
Subexprs = [or(false, true), and(false, true), and(or(false, true), and(false, true))] ;
 false false false
A = B, B = false,
Subexprs = [or(false, false), and(false, false), and(or(false, false), and(false, false))].
```

Note that the output using `write` comes before the answer substitutions. It would be cleaner to separate the evaluation of expressions from printing the results, using a predicate like this:

```
expr_value(Expr, true) :-
    call(Expr),
    !.
expr_value(_Expr, false).
```

This gives:

```
?- phrase(subexprs(and(or(A, B), and(A, B))), Subexprs), bindlist([A,B]), maplist(expr_value, Subexprs, Values).
A = B, B = true,
Subexprs = [or(true, true), and(true, true), and(or(true, true), and(true, true))],
Values = [true, true, true] ;
A = true,
B = false,
Subexprs = [or(true, false), and(true, false), and(or(true, false), and(true, false))],
Values = [true, false, false] ;
A = false,
B = true,
Subexprs = [or(false, true), and(false, true), and(or(false, true), and(false, true))],
Values = [true, false, false] ;
A = B, B = false,
Subexprs = [or(false, false), and(false, false), and(or(false, false), and(false, false))],
Values = [false, false, false].
```

You can then use the `Values` list to print the values for sub-expressions in the same way that you print the values of variables.

Comment: how can i use this in my function called table above?
so a truthtable is printed at the end

Comment: Using `maplist/2` as in my first usage example.

Comment: i am new to prolog so i dont really catch it
can you provide me the syntax in the table function which is 
table(VarList,Expr) :- bindList(VarList), do(VarList,Expr), fail.
?

Comment: i want that it gets printed in one table like this

True True False
True False True
False False True

etc

Comment: i am sorry for disturbing but a small question which will help me alot why when i use phrase(subexprs(and(or(A, B), and(A, B))), Subexprs), bindlist([A,B]), maplist(expr_value, Subexprs, Values).
it prints value for A=B=true only? not other predicates?

Comment: After it prints that, press `;` (semicolon). Prolog will backtrack and give you another solution. As for how to do the printing, just copy the code from my first usage example (the one using `maplist` on `write_expr`) into your `do` predicate and it should mostly work.

Comment: please check this output
phrase(subexprs(bicond(and(impl(A,B),impl(B,A)),bicond(A,B))),Subexprs), bindList([A,B]), maplist(expr_value, Subexprs, Values).
A = B, B = true,
Subexprs = [true impl true, true impl true,  (true impl true)and(true impl true), true bicond true,  (true impl true)and(true impl true)bicond(true bicond true)],
Values = [true, true, true, true, false]

Comment: why it doesnt create the last bicond which wraps all of them? since the equation is bicond(statments)

Comment: I don't know, and it's impossible to tell without your code. Please do all of this: (a) accept my answer above by checking the check mark next to it; (b) open a new question for this new problem; (c) include all of the code needed to run your program in that question; (d) include a link back to this question from that new question.